# Rails Error hitting the url on server start: ExecJS::RuntimeError in Spree/home#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, node.js, ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree

I am trying to setup code on mac os. it worked perfectly on ubuntu. i installed all the gems and when i hit the url after switching on the server i am getting this error. deeply frustrated

```
Showing /Users/ayruskrishna/code/krizda/app/views/spree/shared/_header.html.erb where line #13 raised:

FATAL ERROR: CodeRange::GetNextAllocationBlock Allocation failed - process out of memory

  (in /Users/ayruskrishna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/spree_core-1.2.0/app/assets/javascripts/store/checkout.js.coffee)
Extracted source (around line #13):

10: <%= favicon_link_tag '/assets/favicon1.ico' %>
11: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'store/all', :media => 'screen' %>
12: <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
13: <%= javascript_include_tag 'store/all' %>
14: </head>
15: <body>
16:   <div class="wrap">
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/layouts/spree.html.erb

Rails.root: /Users/ayruskrishna/code/krizda
```

Comment: What version of osx are you using? How much free memory do you have?

Comment: @Tomdarkness I am using Mac OS 10.5.8 and i have a 2 GB RAM. installed everything through home brew.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're using Spree 1.2.0 I'd suggest trying a newer version (v1.2.4 is available in the same stable line). I'd also checkout the Activity Monitor OS X app.. A spree store for me typically uses less than 200MB of RAM.

You could also look at using an alternative web server... http://puma.io/ claims to have a significantly smaller memory footprint than some of the alternatives.

Comment: i think i do have significant amount of memory required to run the spree store. 2 GB RAM is more than enough i guess. Please have a look at this http://postimage.org/image/m9p1quqxj/